# How to extract similar element from a vector?

Tags: r

I have a vector which have following three strings

```
test <- c("www.example.com/topic/university-admission",
          "www.example.com/topic/school-admission",
          "www.example.com/college-admission")
```

I want to extract all the element which have pattern like this `"www.example.com/topic/"`

One way is just looking at vector and extract as per the index location of that element.
But this will be challenging if vector has length of say 100.

Is there any way to do this using string pattern matching?

Comment: `grep("^www.example.com/topic/", test, value = T)`

Comment: what to do for this case  [1] www.example.com/topic/university-admission

[2] www.example.com/topic/university-admission/college                                          [3] www.example.com/topic/school-admission                                                   [4] www.example.com/topic/school-admission/college                                      now i want only                                                                                                        [1] www.example.com/topic/university-admission

[2] www.example.com/topic/school-admission

Comment: ^ means that it will look if the string starts with the given characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test[startsWith(x = test, "www.example.com/topic/")]
# [1] "www.example.com/topic/university-admission" "www.example.com/topic/school-admission"
```

Comment: Thanks its working.....What to do if i have to match "www.example.com/topic/university-admission/college"         Inplace of "university-admission" any string can come....thanks once again

Comment: try: `test[startsWith(x = test, "www.example.com/[^/]/college")]`